# Magnetic Levitation Question

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

For a physics project, I am experimenting with magnetic levitation.
The goal of the project is to levitate a magnet on top of a plate of material. The guidelines for the project are that the plate cannot be magnetic but it should be conductive. I first thought of eddy currents so I got a copper plate about 5 mm thick and two magnets. I put the larger disk magnet on top and the smaller disc one under. I am meant to try and levitate the top magnet by moving the bottom one, I have even tried spinning the bottom magnet with no success...

I spun it pretty quickly but nothing really happened. I tried rotating the magnets along the X, Y and Z axes.
Some questions:

In videos people have thicker plates of copper, will this affect the levitation?

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: *Any ideas?* This is not a discussion forum. Please edit your post to ask a question that has an objectively correct answer. Otherwise, don’t be surprised if it gets closed.

Comment: It sounds like the question you want to ask is "How can I levitate a magnet over a copper sheet?"

Comment: That question is applicable as well. I updated my original question with some more formalized questions.

Comment: You can use an ac source and thus create an electromagnet